# SharePoint roadmap for Office 365

Tags: version

What's the roadmap for SharePoint in Office 365? There's loads on SharePoint 2016 but the Office 365 variant seems to be on different path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint online being part of Office 365, hence there is no specific segregation

Check the below link:

[Office 365 roadmap](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-roadmap)

Lists out various features in development, currently released, rolling out to some tenants, cancelled as well as already launched.

Also this - [Office 365 roadmap watch](http://www.roadmapwatch.com/feature/browse/)

Office blog - [Future of SharePoint](https://blogs.office.com/2016/05/04/the-future-of-sharepoint/)

Below is the image of SP roadmap shown by Jeff Taper (CVP at Microsoft) at Nintex Inspirex

[image]